# Handling new iPhone screen sizes with a background image

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6-plus, asset-catalog

So since the new iPhone 6/6+ came out, I'm a little confused as to how to handle the asset catalogs for a background image.

The options are:

- iPhone 1x (320x480)
- iPhone 2x (640x960)
- iPhone R4 (640x1136)
- iPhone 3x (I assume this is 3*(1x), which would be 960x1440)

What dimensions should I be supplying here, because the resolution of the iPhone 6+ is `1080x1920`, but 3x would be `960x1440`, right?

Comment: The question pointed out does not answer my question. I understand the function of the 3x images for things that are not the full resolution of the device. My question is how I handle background images, as the screen size is not 3x the size of an iPhone 4.

Comment: follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483934/how-to-handle-iphone-screen-sizes-resolution-for-background-images/48563225#48563225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image sizes for new iPhone6/6+ are:

```
For iPhone 6:

    750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
    1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape



For iPhone 6 Plus:

    1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
    2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: So the sizes should be:
iPhone 1x (320x480)

iPhone 2x (750x1334)

iPhone R4 (640x1136)

iPhone 3x (1242x2208)?

Comment: please mentioned the sizes for 1x,2X and 3X images, and dont mentioned iphone6 and iphone 6plus reolution.

Answer (score 1):

**iPhone6 Plus**  2208x1242px  |  736x414pt  |  1920x1080px | 1pt=3px

**iPhone6**       1334x750px   |  667x375pt  |  1334x750px  | 1pt=2px

**iPhone4s**      960x640px    |  480x320px  |  960x640px   | 1pt=2px

[Here for the details](http://iosres.com/)

First one is resource size, second one is device **physical point**, the third one is screen size, iPhone6 plus is a little wired because its screen size not equal to resource size, and each resource will shrink 1.15 time to render.

For your question @3x is based on physicall point of each device. so iPhone6 @3x should be 736x414px X 3 = 2208x1242px