# How to handle iphone screen sizes/resolution for background images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone-x

After the iPhoneX, I am really struggling with the image sizes and naming conventions which supports all devices. Is there any way to use 3x images for 4.7, 5.5 snd 5.8 screens? What are the exact dimensions I should use for an imageview in full screen?

Answer (score 5):

You can use image with `.pdf` format. So you need to manage only single scale image with 1x. It will support all screen sizes so you don't need to mange 1x,2x,3x png. So single image can adjust all devices and also reduce app size.

You can follow these simple steps to implement this method:

Step 1: Get your background image with 1x size in `.png` format and convert it to `.pdf` file

[image]

Step 2: Add that `.pdf` image in your project's `Assets.xcassets` and make you have to select "Single scale" in asset property otherwise you can't add `.pdf` formatted image.

[image]
Step 3: Add set that image in imageview and check with different devices

[image]

Feel free to ask anything. :-)

Comment: I like PDF, but knowing the real truth is good. Check this out : https://bjango.com/articles/idontusepdfs/

Comment: exactly If you know how to manage PDF so it is best way. I am using PDF format from last 10 to 11 months and it's give very clear resolution with very light app size. Follow : https://medium.com/@webalys/die-png-die-how-to-use-vector-icons-in-your-apps-d884c9c63e93 or http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

Comment: Yes .PDF is best than .png and the main thing is we don't need to manage 1x, 2x, 3x and different sizes.